# Add a . every 3rd digit/pad with 0 in SELECT

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

In an MS Access 2007 project, I have a report with the following Record Source:

```
SELECT SomeTable.SomeCol FROM SomeTable;
```

`SomeCol` *should* be either 1, 2, 3, 6, or 9 digits long.

Let's take the 3, 6 & 9 first. Say it is `123` - this should remain as `123`. If it's `123456`, this should be changed to `123.456`. If it's `123456789`, this should be changed to `123.456.789`. If it's `1`, or `65`, this should be changed to `001` and `065` respectively.

How can I modify my `SELECT` to perform these changes? If the length is not 1, 2, 3, 6, or 9, the string should remain unmodified.

Thanks!

Comment: What datatype is your `SomeCol`

Comment: @RowlandShaw It is Text - I know, I know. It should be a number. This is something I unfortunately have no control over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, although it's not very pretty.

In reality, `SomeTable.SomeCol` is a very long string, so it looks much worse on my system. The `SELECT` is part of a much larger query, with multiple `JOIN`'s, so `SomeTable` is required. I have a feeling this is the best solution:

```
SELECT switch(
    len(SomeTable.SomeCol) < 3,
        format(SomeTable.SomeCol, '000'),
    len(SomeTable.SomeCol) = 6,
        format(SomeTable.SomeCol, '000\.000'),
    len(SomeTable.SomeCol) = 9,
        format(SomeTable.SomeCol, '000\.000\.000'),
    true,
        SomeTable.SomeCol
) as SomeCol
FROM SomeTable;
```

Comment: @HansUp This is only to be used in a single report, so I think doing it in the SQL is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your locale, so I don't know whether numbers default to a stop or a comma:

```
SELECT IIf(Len([atext])<4,Format([atext],"000"),Replace(Format(Val([atext]),"#,###"),",",".")) AS FmtNumber
FROM Table2 AS t;
```

You could use a similar format statement without basing your report on a query but make sure you change the name of the control before setting it to a function.

Comment: This helped a lot. I didn't use this exact SQL, but the use of `format()` inspired a much better way to do this.