# Strip out non-numeric characters in SELECT

Tags: sql, regex, ms-access, ms-access-2007

In an MS Access 2007 project report, I have the following (redacted) query:

```
SELECT SomeCol FROM SomeTable
```

The problem is, that `SomeCol` apparently contains some invisible characters. For example, I see one result returned as `123456` but `SELECT LEN(SomeCol)` returns `7`. When I copy the result to Notepad++, it shows as `?123456`.

The column is set to `TEXT`. I have no control over this data type, so I can't change it.

How can I modify my `SELECT` query to strip out anything non-numeric. I suspect RegEx is the way to go... alternatively, is there a `CAST` or `CONVERT` function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You mentioned using a regular expression for this.  It is true that Access' db engine doesn't support regular expressions directly.  However, it seems you are willing to use a VBA user-defined function in your query ... and a UDF can use a regular expression approach.  That approach should be simple, easy, and faster performing than iterating through each character of the input string and storing only those characters you want to keep in a new output string.

```vb
Public Function OnlyDigits(ByVal pInput As String) As String
    Static objRegExp As Object

    If objRegExp Is Nothing Then
        Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        With objRegExp
            .Global = True
            .Pattern = "[^\d]"
        End With
    End If
    OnlyDigits = objRegExp.Replace(pInput, vbNullString)
End Function
```

Here is an example of that function in the Immediate window with "x" characters as proxies for your invisible characters.  (*Any* characters not included in the "digits" character class will be discarded.)

```vb
? OnlyDigits("x1x23x")
123
```

If that is the output you want, just use the function in your query.

```sql
SELECT OnlyDigits(SomeCol) FROM SomeTable;
```

Comment: After seeing your answer, I agree it's better, since it doesn't require every character to be looped through (useful when theres up to 9 characters per string, and 9,500 rows). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no RegEx in Access, at least not in SQL. If you venture to VBA, you might as well use a custom StripNonNumeric VBA function in the SQL statement.

e.g. `SELECT StripNonNumeric(SomeCol) as SomeCol from SomeTable`

```
Function StripNonNumeric(str)
      keep = "0123456789"
      outstr = ""
      For i = 1 to len(str)
          strChar = mid(str,i,1)
          If instr(keep,strChar) Then
              outstr = outstr & strChar
          End If
      Next
      StripNonNumeric = outstr
  End Function
```

Comment: This is perfect! Just for anyone else who happens upon this question. Simply go to the Create tab, and where it says Macro, press the arrow and select Module. Copy this code into the new module, save and close. Then use as `SELECT StripNonNumeric(SomeCol) FROM SomeTable`. Very happy, thank you Richard!

Comment: +1 As you say **RegEx** isn't available in SQL but can be used in Access VBA. As a slight change although I don't imagine it would either increase or decrease the run time, you could always drop the **keep** string and use the built in **IsNumeric** function instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all in a query, combining this question with your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560581/add-a-every-3rd-digit-pad-with-0-in-select/12560936#comment16923664_12560936), you get:

```
SELECT IIf(IsNumeric([atext]),
           IIf(Len([atext])<4,Format([atext],"000"),
               Replace(Format(Val([atext]),"#,###"),",",".")),
           IIf(Len(Mid([atext],2))<4,Format(Mid([atext],2),"000"),
               Replace(Format(Val(Mid([atext],2)),"#,###"),",","."))) AS FmtNumber
FROM Table AS t;
```

Comment: `SELECT VAL(SomeCol) FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeCol = '123456'` returns `0` (where there is some invisible character before the 1 - the WHERE by itself works)

Comment: The first `IIf(IsNumeric([atext]` means that `val` is applied to the text if the text does not have an odd start character, `val` is applied to `Mid([atext],2)`, that is, remove the start character, when the text does have an odd, non-numeric, start character. The above sql was tested.

Comment: And if the character is not at position 1? What then? It might be in the middle of the string, e.g.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function fExtractNumeric(strInput) As String
' Returns the numeric characters within a string in
' sequence in which they are found within the string
Dim strResult As String, strCh As String
Dim intI As Integer
If Not IsNull(strInput) Then
    For intI = 1 To Len(strInput)
        strCh = Mid(strInput, intI, 1)
        Select Case strCh
            Case "0" To "9"
                strResult = strResult & strCh
            Case Else
        End Select
    Next intI
End If
fExtractNumeric = strResult
```

End Function