# Extracting Numeric data access

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to extract only the numeric data from a database. If there are no numbers it should return 0. Here is some sample data i'm dealing with.

BROK.0995684066-ACT

QCR302136900

pending

SP 33757

548751

376.A-ASA

Is there an easy way to get this done?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? [Strip out non-numeric characters in SELECT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12570564/77335)

Answer (score 1):

Using the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563701/strip-out-non-numeric-characters-in-select/12570564#12570564) I used the posted expression to remove all of the non-numerics leaving me with only the numbers which is exactly what i wanted.