# How to extract all numbers from a string using regex?

Tags: regex, ms-access, vba

I have a table **table1** with a field **phone**. This is a string field that is full of other characters besides the number. I want to extract all the numbers from the string.

[image]

I tried "[0-9]+" but I only get the first group of numbers in each row.
I tried searching online but the regexes I tried were incompatible with access.
Please explain the regex as well. Thanks.

This is the VBA regex function I'm using:

```
Function myRegex(ByRef myString As String, ByVal pattern As String) As String
   Dim rgx As New RegExp
    Dim colMatches As MatchCollection
    With rgx
        .pattern = pattern
        .ignoreCase = True
        .Global = False
        .Multiline = False
        Set colMatches = .Execute(myString)
    End With
    If colMatches.Count > 0 Then
        myRegex = colMatches(0).Value
    Else
        myRegex = ""
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: [Public Function OnlyDigits(ByVal pInput As String) As String](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12570564/77335)

Comment: Can you [edit] to paste the code snippet you are running to perform the regex. You may need to run the regex mutliple times rather than just changing the pattern

Comment: @HansUp, "^\d" matches only the beginning of the string.

Comment: @Rhumborl, I've added my code, but I really do not want to run multiple time. I'm sure there must be a regex to extract all numbers from a string.

Comment: `OnlyDigits("111Qs 233322")` returns the string "111233322".  If that is not what you want, please clarify what you want instead.

Comment: BTW, you can use `"\d+"` instead of `"[0-9]+"`.  Both match one or more consecutive digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... but I only get the first group of numbers in each row.

First issue is that `.Global = False` means find only the first match.  If you want to find *all* matches, you need `.Global = True`

Second issue is that your function returns only the first match (`colMatches(0)`) from the `MatchCollection`.  So even after you change `.Global` to `True`, the function will still return only the first match.  If you want to return a string which contains *all* matches, you can concatenate the values of all the matches in `colMatches`.

The following version of the function does what I think you want.

```vb
Function myRegex(ByRef myString As String, ByVal Pattern As String) As String
    Dim rgx As New RegExp
    Dim colMatches As MatchCollection
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strOutput As String
    With rgx
        .Pattern = Pattern
        .IgnoreCase = True
        '.Global = False
        .Global = True
        .Multiline = False
        Set colMatches = .Execute(myString)
    End With
    If colMatches.Count > 0 Then
        'myRegex = colMatches(0).Value
        For i = 0 To (colMatches.Count - 1)
            strOutput = strOutput & colMatches(i).Value
        Next
    'Else
        'myRegex = ""
    End If
    myRegex = strOutput
End Function
```

However I think [OnlyDigits()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12570564/77335) is a simpler approach.  The strategy there is to discard any character which is not a digit.  Compare that function with yours.