# String Extraction between two characters

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm working in Microsoft Access 2010 and I have a table and column [tblData]![Associate Name] with data formatted like Smith, John (123456). Obviously, this shows last name, first name, and the employee ID number (which can vary between 5 to 6 digits). My issue is that I need to extract the employee ID number from this string and I'm struggling to use the correct combination of `Left`, `Right`, `Mid` with the `InStr` function.

Comment: Why are you storing the data like this at all? This is in essence a calculated column, which is bad design.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't my data. I was just asked to manipulate it lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `InStr()` to find the position of the `(` character.

Next use `Mid()` to extract the substring starting one character after the `(`

And then `Val()` will give you a number from the remaining digits; it ignores anything after the last digit.

If you want the result as a string instead of number, you can use `CStr()` to convert it.

Here is an example from the Immediate window:

```vb
Associate_Name = "Smith, John (123456)"
? InStr(1, Associate_Name, "(")
 13 
? Mid(Associate_Name, InStr(1, Associate_Name, "("))
(123456)
? Mid(Associate_Name, InStr(1, Associate_Name, "(") + 1)
123456)
? Val(Mid(Associate_Name, InStr(1, Associate_Name, "(") + 1))
 123456 
? CStr(Val(Mid(Associate_Name, InStr(1, Associate_Name, "(") + 1)))
123456
```

Comment: Also see whether [OnlyDigits()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12570564/77335) would be useful for your situation.

Comment: Ohhh ok that makes so much sense on what the through process is when doing this kind of thing. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Yes, I thought the code example would explain it better than my words did.  :-)  You're welcome.